# How to redirect kubernetes job output to Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, xunit, azure-aks

We have Azure Kubernetes in our company. The situation is that certain integration tests should be run within Azure Kubernetes. However, they should be run as part of Azure DevOps pipeline. The way we've solved it initially, is deploying those tests as a job, then waiting for the job to complete with certain timeout. Here is the piece of the Azure DevOps yaml pipeline that deploys the helm chart of the test runner job and waits for the completion

```yaml
- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: 'Upgrade Helm for TestRunner'
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceConnection: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    namespace: default
    command: upgrade
    chartType: FilePath
    chartPath: '../$(HelmChartPath)'
    releaseName: $(testRunnerReleaseName)
    valueFile: "../values.${{ parameters.environmentName }}.yaml"

- task: Kubernetes@1
  displayName: "Wait for the test runner job to complete"
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
    namespace: default
    command:  wait
    outputFormat: none
    arguments:  --for=condition=complete --timeout=35m job/$(testRunnerName)-job
```

However, this implementation has several major drawbacks

1. If the tests fail, the pipeline will only fail after the timeout expires. In our case it's 35 minutes. Thus, the feedback loop is extremely slow
2. Whenever tests are failed, we have 0 information in the pipeline itself why. So, we will have to go to the specific pod in AKS and view the logs to understand what went wrong. This adds major overhead to developer's experience
3. We can't view the test execution logs except visiting AKS pod logs.

The ideal sitation would have been the following

1. Somehow redirect the logs from the AKS pod to azure devops pipeline
2. Pipeline should fail if the tests fail
3. Pipeline should succeed if the tests succeed

As I understand, we somehow need to pass some kind of identifier of the currently executing pipeline to the pod and use some API to forward the logs to Azure Pipeline. How could we achieve this easily?

Comment: helm test --logs https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_test/

Comment: You have to use the task PublishTestResults with failTaskOnFailedTests: true. To get the test results you have to mount a shared volume to execute a kubectl cp from the pipeline.

Comment: @Laurianti thanks for the comment. That was definitely helpful. We've migrated to helm test instead of jobs, and that solved one of the problems - we have immediate feedback. As for shared volume, that's a good idea! We can try that as well. For the time being, we just dumped the logs of the pod using `helm test --logs` option and that's good enough for now.
However, we still have the issue of redirecting pod logs to azure devops pipeline in real time.

Comment: @Laurianti do you have an example for that? I have the result in a file on the pod an I've tried to copy the file to the agent with an AzureCLI task (inlineScript: 'kubectl cp test/pod-name:test-output.xml) but with no success.